Black bios screen with non blinking underscore on laptop
I've been trying to access my BIO settings, in order to change the boot order to boot from USB first.
When booting the computer and holding down F12, the BIOS menu comes up fine, and I can access the "Device Configuration" and "Change Boot Mode Settings" options, but when I select "BIOS Setup" the screen turns black with a non blinking underscore on screen on top right.
Operating boots up fine,
Dell inspiron 3505 Amd Ryzen 3 3250u
